# ELK stack configure alert email

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Trying to configure email in Kibana, documentation states to modify elasticsearch.yml

[image]

```
elasticsearch\config\elasticsearch.yml
```

Added the following at the bottom:

```
xpack.notification.email.account:
    account:
        smtp:
            auth: false
            starttls.enable: true
            starttls.required: false
            host: localhost
            port: 25
```

When I start service and do "test send email" i get error sending email
How does one configure emailing for alerts.

Am i editing the right configuration file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. I was able to enable emailing through gmail.

```
elasticsearch\config\elasticsearch.yml



# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
xpack.notification.email.account:
    gmail_account:
        profile: gmail
        smtp:
            auth: true
            starttls.enable: true
            host: smtp.gmail.com
            port: 587
            user: yourmeail@gmail.com
            password: ******* your password
```